# Changing the person/group select component in Alfresco

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I need to dynamically change the search term that one set using the person/group select panel/component in Alfresco. I though this code was here: webapps\share\components\people-finder. However, I realized that the files inside this directory are not being used, because if I delete them the person/group select component still works.

So where is the code related with this component?

thank you!

Comment: What version of Alfresco are you using?

Comment: 4.2.f! I believe Im looking for the conponent that represents bpm:assignee.